# opposite of setContentView

Tags: android, layout, view, android-activity

in my Activity subclass OnCreate method i use setContentView(XXX) to setup the window layout.
In certain circumstances it is necessary, at 'OnStart' time, for this Activity to be stopped.
Calling in the OnStart the Activity.finish() method, actually stop the execution but cause a ugly flicker effect where my layout is shown for an instant before application dies.

Question is:
is there an opposite of setContentView? 
Can I use an ipotetic ***clearContentView*** to empty the layout and avoid the flickering?

Thanks in advance
L.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can pass null to setcontentview as below

```
setContentView(null);
```

Using this your activity defines null to layout view

Comment: This throws a NullPointerException to me.

Comment: It throws NPE - at least with JB.

Comment: At that time only 2.3 available, I will check for latest versions & back soon with solution

Comment: From 4.0 a NPE is thrown

Answer (score 6):

You can make a clean xml `clear.xml` with no content and

```
setContentView(clear);
```

You can try, but i'm not sure it'll help .

Comment: This is noway the opposite. this is setting changing content view with another one no matter the content. Exact opposite would be replaced by previous one which was set before calling setContentView(view)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set TextView with no text inspite of creating new xml.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("");
setContentView(tv);
```

I'm not sure it'll help, too

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't just use a View.. View blankView = new View(this); setContentView(blankView);

Comment: i was newbee then :)